# Drawing A Histogram Java (statistical overflow)

Tags: java

Hi so I'm working on a program that is designed to take a set of random Gaussian numbers in an array and put them into a textual version of a histogram (not much fun). I still have a long ways to go, but I'm stuck at this point because when I compile and run my code, I recieve an error of java.lang.StackOverflowError.  It is referring to my client program that runs the statistics of the numbers (mean, sum, variance, etc.) and says the error occurs in line 44. Here is my code so far:

```
public class DescriptiveStatistics
{
public static void main(String args[])
{
 double data[] = DataSet.getGaussianNumbers(1000);


}
    public static double getMinimum()
    {
    double[] nums = DataSet.getGaussianNumbers(1000);
    double min = nums[0];
    System.out.println("min value is " + min);
    return getMinimum();
    }

    public static double getMaximum()
    {
    double[] nums = DataSet.getGaussianNumbers(1000);
    double max = nums[nums.length-1]; 
    return getMaximum();
    }


     public static double getSum()
     {
     double[] nums = DataSet.getGaussianNumbers(1000);



     return getSum();
     }

     public static double getMean()
     {
     int n1 = 1;
     int n2 = 3;
     int n3 = 5;
     int n4 = 7;
     int n5 = 9;
     int sum = n1 + n2 + n3 + n4 + n5;
     double mean = (double)sum/5.0;

     return getMean();
     }

     public static double getVariance()
     {
     int n1 = 1;
     int n2 = 3;
     int n3 = 5;
     int n4 = 7;
     int n5 = 9;
     int sum = n1 + n2 + n3 + n4 + n5;
     double mean = (double)sum/5.0;

     double difference1 = (n1 - mean) * (n1 - mean);
     double difference2 = (n2 - mean) * (n2 - mean);
     double difference3 = (n3 - mean) * (n3 - mean);
     double difference4 = (n4 - mean) * (n4 - mean);
     double difference5 = (n5 - mean) * (n5 - mean);
     double Sigma = difference1 + difference2 + difference3 + difference4 + difference5;  
     double variance = (0.2 * Sigma);

     return getVariance();

     }

     public static double getStandardDeviation()
     {
     int n1 = 1;
     int n2 = 3;
     int n3 = 5;
     int n4 = 7;
     int n5 = 9;
     int sum = n1 + n2 + n3 + n4 + n5;
     double mean = (double)sum/5.0;

     double difference1 = (n1 - mean) * (n1 - mean);
     double difference2 = (n2 - mean) * (n2 - mean);
     double difference3 = (n3 - mean) * (n3 - mean);
     double difference4 = (n4 - mean) * (n4 - mean);
     double difference5 = (n5 - mean) * (n5 - mean);
     double Sigma = difference1 + difference2 + difference3 + difference4 + difference5;  
     double variance = (0.2 * Sigma);

     double deviation = Math.sqrt(variance);

     return getStandardDeviation();
     }

}
```

I know my arithmetic is messy, but they work. I'm just not sure why I'm getting the error. If there are any other glaring mistakes, please let me know! Thanks!

Comment: infiniiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiityyyyy of getSum() yay party!

Comment: Look in the main(), looks like you are calling none of the methods in the DescriptiveStatistics class. Where is DataSet class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every single one of your methods should throw a `StackOverflowError`.

```
public static double getMean()
 {
 int n1 = 1;
 int n2 = 3;
 int n3 = 5;
 int n4 = 7;
 int n5 = 9;
 int sum = n1 + n2 + n3 + n4 + n5;
 double mean = (double)sum/5.0;

 return getMean();
 }
```

By returning `getMean()` in the method `getMean()`, you are creating infinite recursion. I think you want to be returning `mean`. (All your other methods do the same thing, so you might want to look into fixing those too.)

Answer (score 2):

```
 public static double getSum()
 {
    double[] nums = DataSet.getGaussianNumbers(1000);
    return getSum(); // ****
 }
```

ouch!

You've got near-infinite recursion. This code is enough to show you what's going on:

```
public class TestGetSum {

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      double d = getSum();
   }

   public static double getSum() {
      double[] nums = getGaussianNumbers(1000);
      return getSum(); // ****
   }

   public static double[] getGaussianNumbers(int i) {
      return new double[i];
   }

}
```

since getSum() calls itself in its return statement, it keeps calling itself over and over recursively until all memory is used up.

Comment: Is he even calling the getSum() method?

Comment: And he got infinite recursion in all of his methods.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, almost all of your methods look like this:

```
while (true) {
    ...
}
```

This is bad, because *the methods will never stop executing themselves unless the program crashes* with a `StackOverFlow` error. If you've created a `while (true)` loop or any other infinite loop, make sure there is a `break` or `return` statement inside the loop. If you've created a method, **make sure you don't set the return value to the method name** as in the following example:

```
boolean dontDoThis(int iWillCrash) {
    return dontDoThis();
}
```

Hope this helps! :)

**P.S.** Just to lighten things up a bit, [here is a *real* StackOverFlow error!](http://www.stackoverflow.com/error)